# How to access spring application deployed in openshift's tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat7, openshift

I have created a simple spring boot application and deployed it to openshift redhat (as Tomcat 7 application) through my OpenShift explorer from my Eclipse SDE. 
 
When I tried to access from my openshift domain url, It showing status 404 but same application is working fine in my local.

My local url: 
http://localhost:8082/TestApp/testme.do

My openshift url:
http://test-{mydomain}.rhcloud.com/TestApp/testme.do

Is there any specific way to access the openshift application url?

Thanks in advance for those giving assistance, Please let me know if you need additional details.

Regards,
Dhana.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community....... Most providers do not allow direct port connections. Check if you are hosting your database/etc at port 80, instead of 8082. Finally, on your server, are you receiving the correctly encoded request? What does the logs say?

Comment: Hi Bonatti,
Thanks for attempting to assist me!
Openshift is a common provider to run our application in cloud. The port I mentioned is only for my local server (Since 8080 is already in use by my another application, I hosted this application @ 8082 locally). I don't have any issues with my local environment, where application runs successfully.
The area where I am struggling is, I don't know the context path to access my application hosted remotely in openshit tomcat.

Comment: While I myself do not use Openshift, I have used Apache Tomcat on older days. What I meant on my comment is, that you check on your code, for refferences to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and any other loopback address. Since the question is very broad, we have to guess the common mistakes first. If you can, try to edit your question, and add relevant details, such as any error log, any "deployment" inconsistencies (such as git commit/pushes), and the eventual attempts you already tried. These will allow us to gather information, and check what is expected, and compare with what happened.